# When the command is executed python manage.py runserver

Tags: django

When the command is executed :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

error :

```
C:\Users\Mr-py-dj\Desktop\sageteam-project\venv\lib\site-packages\khayyam\algorithms.py:19: UserWarning: The C extension is not available. Switching to fallback python pure algorithms,so it's about 1000X slower than C implementation of the algorithms.
"The C extension is not available. Switching to fallback python pure algorithms,"
```

why???

Comment: This does not appear to be a Django question at all. What is khayyam\algorithms.py?

Answer (score 0):

Install `build-essential` and `python2-dev` or `python3-dev`

Download the [latest release](https://github.com/pylover/khayyam/releases) and extract. then

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
pip install -e .
```